# Finding other divisors of a polynomial given one of its divisors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $3x^4-6x^3+kx^2-8x-12$ is divisible by $(x-3)$ then it is also divisible by?
>
> $(A)\quad 3x^2-4\quad (B)\quad 3x^2+4\quad (C)\quad 3x^2+x\quad (D)\quad 3x^2-x$

How to solve the problem in general and what to do if there are multiple options available?

Let $p(x)=3x^4-6x^3+kx^2-8x-12$, whence we can write $p(x)=(x-3)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. Now, $p(3)=0\Rightarrow k=-5$. It is also seen that $p(-1)=0$.  Then $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x+1)$ also and I can also write $p(x)=(x+1)(x-3)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$. But this is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: From $p(x)=(x+1)(x-3)g(x)$, comparing coefficients of $x^4$, the leading term in $g(x)$ must be $3x^2$ and comparing constant term, the constant  term in $g(x)$ must be 4. Of the given answers, only (B) has these. Hence answer is (B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion your strategy is good. Evidently you are in the worst case and the problem is asking for something about the factors of $p$ that you don't know yet. It suffices that you compute the quotient $q$ of $p$ by $(x+1)(x-3)=x^2-2x-3$.

P.S. You can rule out (C) and (D) because $x$ divides those polynomials but not $p$. So the answer is (A) or (B). If you know that **at least one of the answers is true** then you can also note that $-12=p(0)=(0+1)(0-3)q(0)$, that is $q(0)=4$ so the answer should be (B) (same remark of mathlove).

Answer (score 1):

You already know that $p(x)=(x+1)(x-3)g(x)=(x^2-2x-3)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$.

Now, you can divide $p(x)$ by $(x+1)(x-3)=x^2-2x-3$ to find the answer.

But with the options, note that the constant term of $g(x)$ has to be $-12/(-3)=4$.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $p(x)=3x^4-6x^3+kx^2-8x-12$ is divisible by $(x-3)$.

Hence $0 = p(3) = 9k + 45$. Hence $k= -5$ and 
$p(x)=3x^4-6x^3-5x^2-8x-12.$ You also noticed that 
$p(-1) = 0.$ Using synthetic division, we get

\begin{array}{r|rrrrr}
     &    3 &  -6 &  -5 &  -8 & -12 \\
   3 &   0 &   9 &   9 &  12 &  12\\
     & --- & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
     &   3 &   3 &   4 &   4 & \\
  -1 &   0 &  -3 &   0 &  -4\\
     & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
     &   3 &   0 &   4 \\
\end{array}

You interpret this as $p(x) = (x-3)(x+1)(3x^2 + 4)$